# How to keep thread open in Windows service

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, service

I'm developing a Windows Service that does several things including listening to incoming Serial Port messages at several different ports.

The listening happens by opening a thread per serial device.

I'm still wondering how i can keep my threads open while listening.
I tried some things like a while(true){} loop, which works but takes the cpu to 100% when having multiple devices connected.

In a console app, i can use console.readline(), i'm looking for something similar and easy.

This is what i have now, how can i make it work?

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        var devices = MyService.Kernel.Get<IDevicesService>();
        foreach (var device in devices.ComDevices.List())
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() => StartKeypadThread(device.Id));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void StartKeypadThread(int deviceId)
    {
        var devices = MyService.Kernel.Get<IDevicesService>();
        var device = devices.ComDevices.Find(deviceId);
        var c = new SerialConnector(device);
        c.SerialDataRecieved += c_SerialDataRecieved;
        c.Start();
        //Console.ReadLine(); --> I know, sounds stupid, it's a Service :)
        //while (true)
        //{
        //}
    }
```

Comment: There is no point to using a thread when you have a "DataReceived" event.  Either don't use that event and call a regular blocking Read() or don't use a thread.  And observe the need for OnStart/OnStop in a service, you always need an AutoResetEvent to detect that the service should pause or stop.  You can call its WaitOne() method to block the thread..

Comment: What @Hans said. You don't have to keep your program running in a service's OnStart() method, in fact, you should return from it as soon as possible. Your program will keep running until the service is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for the help.
I'm not experienced in threads, so maybe i indeed don't need to use these threads, but when i didn't, i got an error "Safe Handle Has been Closed" in another part of the service (where i didn't use these Com devices).

To solve the problem quickly and keep using these threads, i found another solution by using the WaitHandler.

If somebody needs it, here is how i did:

```
public static void Start()
{
    var devices = MyService.Kernel.Get<IDevicesService>();
    foreach (var device in devices.ComDevices.List())
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() => StartKeypadThread(device.Id));
        thread.Start();
    }
}

public static void StartKeypadThread(int deviceId)
{
    var devices = MyService.Kernel.Get<IDevicesService>();
    var device = devices.ComDevices.Find(deviceId);
    var c = new SerialConnector(device);
    c.SerialDataRecieved += c_SerialDataRecieved;
    c.Start();
    var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: This WaitHandle approach is the same thing as the sleep. It just hangs forever. No need to use a named handle either. Maybe the problem is that the SerialConnector objects are GC'ed? Put them into a global/static list and let all the threads exit. Right now you're using each thread as a GC handle...

Answer (score 0):

Answering literally: `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.

Why do you need to "hang" the thread, though, especially forever? Maybe you should use a ManualResetEvent that you signal when you want the service to stop.

Also, starting all those child threads to just attach events is not needed. Each of those will run for 1ms or so and then just exit. Waste of time.

Comment: Well it doesn't need to hang foreverer, it must listen forever, sleep is not good for this.

Comment: @RubinhoG. what are you talking about? Sleeping one thread does not influence the other.

Comment: If it sleeps, can it still handle the c_SerialDataRecieved event in that thread?
Anyway, it works now, being not experienced in threads and services, i'm happy it works :)

Comment: If it waits, can it then handle an event? No. That event is always raised on a different thread. There is no way ti hijack a thread.